# Use of Enum when members are the same as another class's public variables

Tags: java, c#, oop, enums

I have a situation where I feel like I'm doing something wrong, and I suspect there's a MUCH more efficient way to do things.

I have a class with some variables:

```
public class Structure  {
    public float size;
    public float pos_x;
    public float pos_y;
    public float pos_z;
}
```

And I have an enum with these members which are exactly the same as the above fields:

```
public enum StructureProperty {
    SIZE,
    POS_X,
    POS_Y,
    POS_Z,
}
```

I have AnotherClass that needs to store a single StructureProperty, and its associated value.

```
public class AnotherClass {
    public StructureProperty property;
    public float value;
    public float ID;
    public float parentID;
    ..some methods and things
}
```

I have a method that grabs this other class, and looks to see which property to update using the enum:

```
void UpdateStructure (AnotherClass anotherClassInstance) {
    switch (anotherClassInstance.property) {

    case StructureProperty.SIZE:
        Structure.size += anotherClassInstance.value;
        break;

    ... for all other cases 
    but the logic might be different 
    (not always +=, sometimes several lines)

}
```

This method needs to check to see which property to update in the structure, and then update it. I feel like I might be breaking some kind of object oriented approach here since I need to maintain both a list of enums and  a list of variables in Structure. Note that I foresee frequently adding and removing properties as I build my program. Hopefully someone can steer me in the right way of making this code more future-proof.

I'm programming in c#, but I think this question applies to all major OO programming languages.

Thanks.

Comment: Not really clear what you trying to do... maybe using set of delegates that update particular property instead of enum values would work. Such approach definitely is less efficient from raw CPU speed point of view than direct manipulation of struct fields, but at least more extensible. If using it watch out for structs being copied - you may need to sprinkle `ref` everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, How can I make it clearer what I want to do? I can update the question, I'm just wondering what isn't clear. I'll look into struct fields, never used them before.

Comment: The problem is you described what code does, but not what you want to achieve - so suggestions would be limited to minor changes to what you have instead of alternative approaches to actual problem which you possibly looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering this from a Java standpoint. I am sure c# will have similar constructs. I don't see any necessity of maintaining a Structure class and a StructureProperty enum. Assuming these properties need to be modified at runtime, and there is no use case of storing them in a properties file, I think Structure and StructureProperty can be consolidated into one Enum.

Here's how you could think in that direction :

```
public class StructurePropertyExample {

private static enum StructureProperty {

    SIZE(0.0f), POS_X(0.0f), POS_Y(0.0f), POS_Z(0.0f);

    private float value;

    private StructureProperty(float value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public float getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(float value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) {

    float newValue = 1.23f;

    for (StructureProperty property : StructureProperty.values()) {
        switch (property) {
            case SIZE: property.setValue(newValue);
                       break;
            case POS_X : // similar as above
            case POS_Y :
            case POS_Z : 
        }
    }

}
```

}

In case we are talking about different data types, the enum can be changed to hold wrapped Objects as below :

```
    private static enum StructureProperty {

    SIZE, POS_X, POS_Y, POS_Z;

    private Object value;

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
};
```

Comment: Amazing! Do you know if there's any way to have different types for the value? like have some values ints, others floats?

Comment: Unfortunately, in Java, enums don't support dynamic type declarations. Based on your question, I assumed you only needed to take care of float values. If you have that requirement of supporting various types then you will have to play with wrapping those primitives as Object. For example, you could wrap an int as an Integer. I edited the answer with a new suggestion.

Comment: Hi Partha, I posted a new question that is closely related to this one, but about a different issue. I was wondering if you could please take a look! http://stackoverflow.com/q/36881443/4163879

Comment: Thanks, I already saw your question and will try to think of a way of coming up with a possible solution, we might have to think a bit more and apply a design pattern here. Let me think! :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't find problem with your Sturcture class and defining enums. I find AnotherClass problematic, i.e. it is containing unnecessary properties which might never get used depending on your StructureProperty enum. So I would rather break this AnotherClass into specefic StructureUpdater classes and instantiate the specific Updater class (may be by using Factory) to update the Structure.

Another approach can be to write extension methods on the Structure class itself to update it like

```
public static class StructureExtensions
{
    public static void UpdateSize(this Structure structure, float size)
    {
        structure.size += size;
    }

    public static void UpdateX(this Structure structure, float x)
    {
        structure.pos_x += x;
        //any other update on strucutre

    }
}
```

and then you can use these directly on structure itself

```
        Structure structure = new Structure();
        structure.UpdateSize(123);
        structure.UpdateX(34);
```

Comment: Yeah good idea with putting the methods in. But the issue with my enum setup is that if I need to add/delete a new property I need to add it in two places. And I remember when I was first learning programming that was considered a big nono.