# Design issue: need instances of an enum member as (property, value) pair

Tags: java, c#, enums

This question is a spinoff of my previously answered question. [Use of Enum when members are the same as another class's public variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36806015/use-of-enum-when-members-are-the-same-as-another-classs-public-variables/36806434?noredirect=1#comment61187827_36806434). In implementing the answer provided, I was faced with another design problem.

I am writing a program to simulate evolution. I have an enum that stores a list of possible properties that a protein can code for. Proteins are created from a string of amino acids (i.e. "W", "A", etc). Right now I have a Dictionary that links a Property (enum member) with a character. Similarly, I have the same setup for the Type of protein.

```
public class Protein {
    Property property;
    float value;
    Type type;

    enum Property {
        SIZE,
        ID,     
    }
    enum Type {
        STRUCTURAL,
        NEURAL,
    }


    static Dictionary<string, Property> aminoToProperty
              = new Dictionary<string, Property> {
         {"F", Property.SIZE},
         {"K", Property.ID},
    };

    static Dictionary<string, Type> aminoToType 
         = new Dictionary<string, Property> {
         {"A", Type.STRUCTURAL},
         {"B", Type.NEURAL},
    };


}
```

From another class I am creating proteins based on a long string of characters, then combining them to form structures. Several proteins can add up to create all sorts of properties and values for the structure.

```
Structure structure = new Structure();
Protein protein = new Protein (aminos) // didn't show this method for simplicity
switch (protein.property) {

case Protein.Property.SIZE:
        structure.size += protein.value;
        break;

ONE FOR EVERY PROPERTY...

}

SAME THING FOR EVERY TYPE...
```

My problems:

1) when I want to add a new property to the mix, i need to first add an entry into the enum, then into the dictionary. This makes me think I am violating some kind of best practices.

2) I need to keep a case in my switch for every single property and type, is this unavoidable?

3) Is there a way that I can guarantee that in the two dictionaries, I don't accidentally use the same letter twice? Does it make sense to even have two dictionaries?

4) Perhaps I am approaching this problem completely the wrong way.

Note: In the older linked question I had stored values along with the enums. But here I need to have multiple instances with differing values, so I don't think that solution applies.

Sorry if this is confusing but I'm really stuck on how to best design this to make it future proof. I am writing in c# but I think this question applies to most OO programming languages.

Comment: You need to provide more info to make it more clear. Do you use protein properties\types for anything else other that building structure from them? How do you build protein from string? Types and properties are mutually exclusive (there cannot be type and property with the same letter)? Can you control that string from which you build protein or it comes from external source you have no control of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, forgive me if I'm not familiar with the problem domain; my example may reflect that.

I think you're instincts serve you well as the enum solution seems to violate the [open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

Another way to solve this problem without the need for touching multiple places when adding a new protein property and type is to make ProteinType and ProteinProperty abstract base classes that accept a Structure and operate on it.

The Protein can then aggregate both of the types, accept a Structure and delegate the Structure to the ProteinType and ProteinProperty instances so that the Structure can be modified by the most derived types.

Another thing the can be automated is the lookup of an amino to a ProteinType and ProteinProperty using reflection.

This all may seem like overkill, but the end result is that you are now free to define ProteinType and ProteinProperty classes in isolation without having to worry about modifying other areas of the code.

Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var structure = new Structure();
            var protein = new Protein("F", "B", 0.5F);
            protein.ApplyToStructure(structure);
        }
    }

    public class Protein
    {
        private readonly float _value;
        private readonly ProteinProperty _proteinProperty;
        private readonly ProteinType _proteinType;

        public Protein(string propertyAmino, string typeAmino, float value)
        {
            _proteinProperty = ProteinProperty.FromAmino(propertyAmino);
            _proteinType = ProteinType.FromAmino(typeAmino);
            _value = value;
        }

        public void ApplyToStructure(Structure structure)
        {
            _proteinProperty.ApplyToStructure(structure, _value);
            _proteinType.ApplyToStructure(structure, _value);
        }
    }

    public class Structure
    {
        public float Size { get; set; }
        public float Id { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class ProteinType
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<string, ProteinType> AllProteinTypes = typeof (ProteinType)
            .GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Where(nestedType => typeof (ProteinType).IsAssignableFrom(nestedType))
            .Select(nestedType => (ProteinType) Activator.CreateInstance(nestedType))
            .ToDictionary(proteinType => proteinType.Amino);

        public static ProteinType FromAmino(string amino)
        {
            ProteinType proteinType;
            if (!AllProteinTypes.TryGetValue(amino, out proteinType))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid amino");
            }

            return proteinType;
        }

        public abstract string Amino { get; }

        public abstract void ApplyToStructure(Structure structure, float value);

        private sealed class StructuralProteinType : ProteinType
        {
            public override string Amino { get; } = "A";

            public override void ApplyToStructure(Structure structure, float value)
            {
                // do what you need to do to Structure
            }
        }

        private sealed class NeuralProteinType : ProteinType
        {
            public override string Amino { get; } = "B";

            public override void ApplyToStructure(Structure structure, float value)
            {
                // do what you need to do to Structure
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class ProteinProperty
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<string, ProteinProperty> AllProteinProperties = typeof(ProteinProperty)
            .GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Where(nestedType => typeof(ProteinProperty).IsAssignableFrom(nestedType))
            .Select(nestedType => (ProteinProperty)Activator.CreateInstance(nestedType))
            .ToDictionary(proteinProperty => proteinProperty.Amino);

        public static ProteinProperty FromAmino(string amino)
        {
            ProteinProperty proteinProperty;
            if (!AllProteinProperties.TryGetValue(amino, out proteinProperty))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid amino");
            }

            return proteinProperty;
        }

        public abstract string Amino { get; }

        public abstract void ApplyToStructure(Structure structure, float value);

        private sealed class SizeProteinProperty : ProteinProperty
        {
            public override string Amino { get; } = "F";

            public override void ApplyToStructure(Structure structure, float value)
            {
                structure.Size += value;
            }
        }

        private sealed class IdProteinProperty : ProteinProperty
        {
            public override string Amino { get; } = "K";

            public override void ApplyToStructure(Structure structure, float value)
            {
                // do what you need to do to Structure
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Edit

After reading your question again and trying to wrap my head around the problem domain, I wondering if there's even a distinction between ProteinProperty and ProteinType...seems they are just representations of an amino character that has an effect on the Structure. Also you indicated that aminos are a string of characters.

If this is true, this I would replace ProteinProperty and ProtienType with a single base class: Amino. Additionally, you can have the Amino base class' ApplyToStructure() method take the entire Protein instance so you can access other stuff on it if you need to in the derived Amino classes.

Finally, you can create a collection of Amino instances based on an amino string and apply them to the Structure in a loop.

Here's the updated example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var structure = new Structure();
            var protein = new Protein(0.5F, "FKABAKB");
            protein.ApplyToStructure(structure);
        }
    }

    public class Protein
    {
        private readonly ReadOnlyCollection<Amino> _aminos;

        public Protein(float value, string aminos)
        {
            Value = value;
            _aminos = aminos
                .Select(Amino.FromAminoCharater)
                .ToList()
                .AsReadOnly();
        }

        public float Value { get; }

        public void ApplyToStructure(Structure structure)
        {
            foreach (var amino in _aminos)
            {
                amino.ApplyToStructure(structure, this);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Structure
    {
        public float Size { get; set; }
        public float Id { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class Amino
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<char, Amino> AllAminos = typeof(Amino)
            .GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Where(nestedType => typeof(Amino).IsAssignableFrom(nestedType))
            .Select(nestedType => (Amino)Activator.CreateInstance(nestedType))
            .ToDictionary(proteinProperty => proteinProperty.AminoCharacter);

        public static Amino FromAminoCharater(char aminoCharacter)
        {
            Amino amino;
            if (!AllAminos.TryGetValue(aminoCharacter, out amino))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid amino");
            }

            return amino;
        }

        public abstract char AminoCharacter { get; }

        public abstract void ApplyToStructure(Structure structure, Protein protein);

        private sealed class SizeProperty : Amino
        {
            public override char AminoCharacter { get; } = 'F';

            public override void ApplyToStructure(Structure structure, Protein protein)
            {
                structure.Size += protein.Value;
            }
        }

        private sealed class IdProperty : Amino
        {
            public override char AminoCharacter { get; } = 'K';

            public override void ApplyToStructure(Structure structure, Protein protein)
            {
                // do what you need to do to Structure
            }
        }

        private sealed class StructuralType : Amino
        {
            public override char AminoCharacter { get; } = 'A';

            public override void ApplyToStructure(Structure structure, Protein protein)
            {
                // do what you need to do to Structure
            }
        }

        private sealed class NeuralType : Amino
        {
            public override char AminoCharacter { get; } = 'B';

            public override void ApplyToStructure(Structure structure, Protein protein)
            {
                // do what you need to do to Structure
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also note this addresses the concern of accidentally introducing duplicates. If you define an Amino class with a letter already taken up by another, your app will crash and burn immediately instead of having a subtle bug.

Comment: Using reflection? In my opinion  reflection is something you should use if you must. Here you don't need to use reflection at all.

Comment: The value proposition of reflection in the example in conjunction with the abstract classes is that it is impossible to forget to "register" the the ProteinType and ProteinPropery types with an amino without causing a compile error. Also in the example the reflection hit is taken once when the type initializers run; there's no additional impact as the program runs since the results are cached. This sort of bootstrapping is done often with convention-based IoC containers.

Comment: And it's use also addresses the concern of remembering to modify other aspects of the code when introducing a new ProteinType and ProteinProperty. You just define the class and you're done...minimizing maintenance and reducing the chance of introducing  bugs. To me this seems worth it if there are a lot of these types that need to be added.

Comment: This seems like a perfect solution. Just one part that's unclear still. Am I understanding the following correctly?: Where you define the dictionaries, the 4 lines of code in the definition are finding all the sealed classes that you've defined just below, then seeing which amino they define as their property Amino. Then entering this info into the dictionary?

Comment: Yup. In fact, as I'm reading your original question and trying to wrap my head around the problem domain, I'm even wondering if there's a real distinction between ProteinProperty and ProteinType...I wonder if the two could really just be merged into something called ProteinAmino

Comment: Yes there actually is a very important distinction. I simplified my code in the original question and left out hundreds of lines of code haha

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks again Rafael. Using your pattern with abstract and sealed inner classes, i've actually rewritten a ton of my code to improve readability and keeping logic gathered in one place. Thanks so much for helping me improve my programming!

Comment: Glad I could help! The problem domain looks fascinating; wish I understood it and could help more!

Comment: @RafaelDowlingGoodman Rafael, one more question if you don't mind :) Using code based off your suggestions, I ran into a problem. I want to create a protein directly so I can have it give back the string that would have created it. I'm having trouble constructing the protein from scratch. I would love something like "new Protein.StructuralType.IDProperty(value)", but that instead would give me an IDProperty. I tried making some kind of abstract static methods called "Build(value)", but abstract static methods don't exist (in c# at least). Another thought was a builder pattern of some kind.

Comment: It seems like we're already creating proteins from scratch (e.g. new Protein("F", "B", value)). To have a protein return the amino string it was created from, just save off the strings passed into the constructor, or better yet return the values already available from _proteinType.Amino and _proteinProperty.Amino (assuming we're going off the first example). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I can understand you problem as I have been there before. See the problem with enum is it can not be extended as there is no inheritance mechanism to do so.  So adding new property or type means you modify your enums and thus inviting compatibility breaking issues and deployment of new exe or DLL is required. Enums are good when choices are static from the beginning. For example

Direction : Left, Top, Right, Bottom.

Orientation: Horizontal, Vertical.

Now your case is the typical requires extension of enums which is not doable so how would you write some thing which does that. Simple answer is dump the enums. Change your fields Property and Type to string instead of enum. Now provide virtual methods to parse Property or Type to build your structure. Here is the psuedo code:

```
public class Protein {
    string property;
    float value;
    string type;

    static Dictionary<string, string> aminoToProperty= new Dictionary<string, string> {
     {"F", "SIZE"},
     {"K", "ID"},
    };

    static Dictionary<string, Type> aminoToType = new Dictionary<string, string> {
     {"A", "STRUCTURAL"},
     {"B", "NEURAL"},
    };
```

Now changes in your switch statement:

```
protected virtual void assignValues(Protein Protein){

    switch (protein.property.ToUpper()) {

        case "SIZE":
        structure.size += protein.value;
        break;

        //ONE FOR EVERY PROPERTY...

    }

    //SAME THING FOR EVERY TYPE...
}
```

Now key here is the method "assignValues" declared virtual so that you can override it in order to cater for new property or type. Someone else even outside your assembly, designs his class inheriting from your Protein class can add properties or types and can successfully manage it without much hassle.

I again emphasise, use enum If you are sure that it contains all possible choices without a need of any changes. You have got everything you need in terms of choices at the beginning then enum is your best buddy.

Comment: There is an inheritance mechanism available in enum (in Java), but that's when you declare the instances all inside the same enum enclosure, so that's a constraint anyway.but just wanted to point out.

Comment: This is not about Java. It's c#

Comment: Thats why i wrote "(in Java)" :)

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but the one below is better for future maintenance I think. Thanks a lot though!